# tensorflow_dataset ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'will'

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, checksum, tensorflow-datasets

I created dataset that should mimic the MNIST dataset (by that i mean a dataset with similar information that can be loaded with the tfds.load function) but whenever I try to load it I receive the same error:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\iic_py35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\download\checksums.py", line 83, in _get_sizes_checksums
    checksums[url] = (int(size), checksum)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'will'
```

It has something to do with the downloadmanager function of my dataset script so I'm sharing this part below. I am not really utilizing the download manager functionality because my dataset is stored locally and doesn't need downloading and extracting... but i think that's exactly what creates the issue...

```
  def _split_generators(self, dl_manager):

      return [
          tfds.core.SplitGenerator(
              name=tfds.Split.TRAIN,
              gen_kwargs = dict(
                  num_examples=_TRAIN_EXAMPLES,
                  data_path=r"C:\Users\...\02_Tfds_Structure_for_ICC\front\train",
                  label_path=os.path.join(r"C:\...\02_Tfds_Structure_for_ICC\front", "train_labels.csv"),
              )),
          tfds.core.SplitGenerator(
              name=tfds.Split.TEST,
              gen_kwargs = dict(
                  num_examples=_TEST_EXAMPLES,
                  data_path=r"C:\Users\...\02_Tfds_Structure_for_ICC\front\test",
                  label_path=os.path.join(r"C:\Users\...\02_Tfds_Structure_for_ICC\front", "test_labels.csv"),
              ))
      ]

  def _generate_examples(self, num_examples, data_path, label_path):
      """Yields examples."""
      # TODO(Poopyset_Back): Yields (key, example) tuples from the dataset
      images = _extract_mnist_images(data_path, num_examples)
      labels = _extract_mnist_labels(label_path)
      data = list(zip(images, labels))

      for index, (image, label) in enumerate(data):
        record = {"image": image, "label": label}
        yield index, record


def _extract_mnist_images(image_filepath, nr_of_images):
  image_filepath = mypath
  image_list=[os.path.join(root, name) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_filepath) for name in files if name.endswith(".jpg")]
  data = np.empty((nr_of_images, _SAMPLE_WIDTH, _SAMPLE_HEIGHT, _CHANNELS))
  count = 0
  for image in image_list:
      data[count,:,:,:] = plt.imread(image.format(count))
      count += 1
  data = data.astype(np.uint8)

  return data

def _extract_mnist_labels(labels_filepath):
  labels = np.loadtxt(labels_filepath, dtype=np.int64, delimiter= ",")
  return labels
```

Any help to fix this is highly appreciated
thank you